# Using Images In Panels

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel, jlabel

Given my code below, regardless of any other errors I have in it, how can I get two images on one panel? I have to have this program display 4 images 2 per panel with the first panel having them side by side and the second panel being able to drag and resize? I'm not really sure how to go about this. I can get all 4 images with 4 panels but that's not what the assignment is asking. Thank you!!

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class TwoPanels
{
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
// Creates and displays the primary application frame.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
public static void main (String[] args)
    {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Label Demo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    ImageIcon icon1 = new ImageIcon ("coin.jpg");
    ImageIcon icon2 = new ImageIcon ("coke.jpg");
    ImageIcon icon3 = new ImageIcon ("shuttle.jpg");
    ImageIcon icon4 = new ImageIcon ("sun.jpg");




    JLabel label1, label2;
    label1 = new JLabel ( icon1, SwingConstants.CENTER);
    label1.setHorizontalTextPosition (SwingConstants.LEFT);
    label1.setVerticalTextPosition (SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
    label1 = new JLabel ( icon2, SwingConstants.CENTER);


    label2 = new JLabel (icon3, SwingConstants.CENTER);
    label2.setHorizontalTextPosition (SwingConstants.CENTER);
    label2.setVerticalTextPosition (SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
    label2 = new JLabel (icon4, SwingConstants.CENTER);


    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground (Color.cyan);
    panel.setPreferredSize (new Dimension (960, 640));
    panel.add (label1);
    panel.add (label2);

    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"with the first panel having them side by side and the second panel being able to drag and resize?"*  DYM the panel should be resized when the `JFrame` is resized?  That is relatively easy using the J2SE.  To make a panel that can be resized independent of the top-level container is more tricky, unless using something like a `JSplitPane`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `LayoutManager` to control the layout of child elements in Swing.

- BoxLayout -- single row or single column. This would be good for your purposes..
- BorderLayout -- central with (any or all of) left,right,top,bottom borders.
- GridBagLayout -- a grid.

The left panel (that doesn't resize) can use a BoxLayout. Create it with X_AXIS to lay those two images out side-by-side.

The Frame overall (and specifically it's Content Pane) was specified as resizing into the right panel.. so maybe a BorderLayout is the best way to do that. The left panel would be WEST and not resize, the right panel would be CENTER and resize for all the remaining area.

See:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

One other note: The recommended constants & naming of directions for Swing has changed..  to be more relative to text direction for internationalization etc, rather than absolute direction. LINE_AXIS is now recommended over X_AXIS, though much less clear.

I don't know how your instructor will mark such an area, so just to be aware.

Answer (score 0):

As Thomas W said make sure you get familiar with the layout managers. Especially the GridLayout, BorderLayout and FlowLayout as they will usually let you create almost any type of layout you want. If you want more control and extend your understanding of layouts managers then I suggest looking into GridBagLayout, it is the most powerfull layout manager. To get back to your question, to make a panel dispaly two images you could have a panel, say Panel1, which uses gridlayout with only 2 columns (look at the GridLayout constructors, it takes number of rows and number of columns you desire). Then, you could create two other panels and add them to Panel1, where the other panels are an instance of a class MyCustomPanel which extends JPanel and you override the paintComponent(Graphics g) method to display your desired image. The MyCustomPanel constructor could contain an Image parameter which the method paintComponent can refer to.

Hope it helps. If you need any more help add aa comment I'll be happy to help.